# How can i change published text under date column in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change text of **published** under date column of post list in wordpress.

see below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> You can try using following way.

```
<?php 

function my_custom_columns( $columns ) {
  unset( $columns['date'] );
  $columns['mydate'] = 'My Custom Date';
  return $columns;
}

function my_format_column( $column_name , $post_id ) {
    if($column_name == 'mydate'){
        echo get_the_time( 'l, F j, Y', $post_id )."<br>".get_post_status( $post_id );
    }
}

function my_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['mydate'] = 'mydate';
    return $columns;
}

function my_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'mydate' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'orderby' => 'date'
        ) );
    }
    return $vars;
}

function my_column_init() {
  add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'my_custom_columns' );
  add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'my_format_column' , 10 , 2 );
  add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'my_column_register_sortable' );
  add_filter( 'request', 'my_column_orderby' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'my_column_init' );

?>
```